# webNavigation.onCompleted fires when typing in address bar

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've made a Chrome extension that monitors the webNavigation.onCompleted event to detect when the user navigates to a different page. However, I think the API works a little differently that I initially thought.

Basically, if I set focus to the address bar I immediately get a couple of onCompleted events for google.com (I assume that's the search functionality of the address bar). However, when I then enter certain addresses, such as evolvehq.com. and *before* I hit Enter, I get an onCompleted event for the page. Hitting Enter afterwards doesn't fire another event when the page has actually loaded.

What's going on and how do I reliably detect page changes, i.e. when the destination page has been fully loaded *and* shown to the user?

**Update:** After some more investigation, it looks like hitting Enter after the target website has (ostensibly) been preloaded by Chrome causes a single onBeforeNavigate event (but none of the other events that are supposed to follow it).

Even more interesting, after the history.onVisited event has fired, I get a webNavigation.onErrorOccurred event with net::ERR_ABORTED in it, even though the page loaded just fine.

Argh...

Comment: File a bug report http://new.crbug.com

Comment: Report filed here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117043

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to properly detect navigation events when the webNavigation API clearly is giving inconsistent results? Do others use the history.onVisited event instead, for instance?

Comment: I've thrown the bug into the correct queue. For temporary workaround, you could look at the tab API's [onUpdated event](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated).

Comment: Mike: That's what I was hoping for, too, but as you can see on the debug output in the ticket, I'm not even getting an onUpdated event after the page has loaded, which also really puzzles me.

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory.  I'm not saying that's it.
May be, **Chrome Instant** is firing those events.
And may be, while you continue typing, Chrome Instant change the page causing the ERR_ABORTED.
You can check if Chrome Instant is enabled in Options/Basic/Search.

Comment: It's currently disabled in the browser I'm testing with.